# Why does gam::step.gam return NULL?

Tags: r, gam

Regarding the 'gam' package, though the example in `help("step.gam")`, shown below, works just fine, removing the smoother term 's(x,12)' from consideration in the model yields NULL.  Why?

The s(x,12) term does not end up being included in model `step.object` ... so why would removing it from consideration be a problem?

Works fine:

```
data(gam.data)
gam.object <- gam(y~x+z, data=gam.data)
step.object <-step.gam(gam.object, scope=list("x"=~1+x+s(x,4)+s(x,6)+s(x,12),"z"=~1+z+s(z,4)))
```

Not fine:

```
step.object <-step.gam(gam.object, scope=list("x"=~1+x+s(x,4)+s(x,6),"z"=~1+z+s(z,4)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the code with `trace=2`,

```
data(gam.data)
gam.object <- gam(y~x + z, data=gam.data)
step.object <- step.Gam(gam.object, scope=list("x"=~1+x+s(x,4)+s(x,6),"z"=~1+z+s(z,4)),
               trace = 2)
```

It will print more information about the algorithm results:

```
Start:  y ~ x + z; AIC= 127.7316 
Trial:  y ~  1 + z ; AIC= 234.8821 
Trial:  y ~  s(x, 4) + z ; AIC= 44.0543 
Trial:  y ~  x + 1 ; AIC= 126.5148 
Trial:  y ~  x + s(z, 4) ; AIC= 131.028 
Step:1 y ~ s(x, 4) + z ; AIC= 44.0543 
Trial:  y ~  s(x, 6) + z ; AIC= 43.7495 
Trial:  y ~  s(x, 4) + 1 ; AIC= 43.1799 
Trial:  y ~  s(x, 4) + s(z, 4) ; AIC= 47.1024 
Step:2 y ~ s(x, 4) ; AIC= 43.1799 
Trial:  y ~  s(x, 6) + 1 ; AIC= 42.6681 
Step:3 y ~ s(x, 6) ; AIC= 42.6681
```

The problem is at the last step, i.e. Step 3. Since by default the search direction is both backward and forward, it will search for all the possibilities with one order difference in terms of complexity. There are two trials that could be done, namely `s(x,4) + 1` and `s(x,6) + z`. However, both of those were already computed in Step 1, hence no trials are further computed.

Normally, the search algorithm should terminate when AIC in all of the trials during a step increase. In this case, there is a decrease in AIC during step 2, which leads to step 3, yet no trial was done in step 3. Hence the algorithm does not terminate AND there is no further computation, leads to the result of `NULL`.

Comment: Looks like you've identified a bug.

Comment: I think so too, some `if` conditions could be implemented to avoid resulting `NULL` in the output.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. A work around I found is to increase the maximum number of knots to a number that results in an obvious worsening of the AIC. Then the algorithm is able to define the cutoff better,